# PHP not Displaying Results from MYSQL Timestamp Search

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

Below is my code for searching a date range from MYSQL database. 
I am able to search the dates and it brings up the table headings (Product Desc, New or Own and Date) but it doesn't display any of the results from the database?

Any Ideas on how I need to edit my code in order for it to display the results from the selected date range?

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['find']))
{
?>
<form method = "post" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<table width = "450" align = "center">
    <tr>
    <td><b><i>Please enter date in the field below (i.e. 11-09-2012)</i></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    From&nbsp;:&nbsp;
    <input type = "text" name = "small">
    To&nbsp;:&nbsp;
    <input type = "text" name = "large"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align = "center">
        <input type = "submit" name = "find" value = "SEARCH">
        <input type = "reset" value = "CLEAR FORM">
        </td>   
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
else
{
$small = trim($_POST['small']);
$large = trim($_POST['large']);

$connection = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "user_name", "password") or die("Connection failed. ".myslq_error());
 mysql_select_db("stock") or die("Unable to select db. ".mysql_error());
//Add 1 to the upper range, $large, else it won't make it inclusive
$query = "SELECT * FROM main_stock WHERE curr_timestamp BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(curr_timestamp,'%".$small."') AND DATE_FORMAT(curr_timestamp, '%".($large+1)."') ORDER BY curr_timestamp";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table width = '500' align = 'center'>";
echo "<tr><b>";
    echo "<td>Product Description</td>";
    echo "<td>New or Own?</td>";
    echo "<td>Date</td>";
echo "</b></tr>";
while($record = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$record->product_desc."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$record->newown."</td>";
        $year_part_of_date = explode('-', $record->curr_timestamp);
    echo "<td>".$year_part_of_date[0]."</td>";
        //if you want the full date replace the $year_part_of_date[0] with $record->date
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

}

?>
```

Comment: Have you checked that the query you're generating works, and that you're getting results back?

Comment: What happens when you run the query directly on the database? It seems to make no sense that you are using the $small and $large values to format your date strings.

Comment: You've not escaped your user-tainted variables, so you may have an SQL injection vulnerability in this script.

Comment: andrewsi - When I insert the dates - it displays the table headings (Product Description, New or Own and Date) but doesn't display any results

Comment: @SarahHSL That is because your table headings are not output conditionally.  They are going to be output no matter what happens with the query.

Comment: You should not be using `mysql_query` in new applications because it is extremely dangerous. You haven't escaped any of your user data and are exposing yourself to serious [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/php). New applications should be using `mysqli` or PDO with proper SQL placeholders. These ensure your data is safely stored in the database even if it contains characters like `'` that would cause your application to explode or possibly be exploited by a [SQL injection hacking tool](http://sqlmap.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I would guess your query is not valid.

Assuming that `curr_timestamp` is a MySQL datetime field in format of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, you need to change your input to be in this format for easy comparison.  If you can elaborate on the format of `$small` and `$large` that would be helpful.

You probably want your query to be in this format

```
SELECT * FROM main_stock
WHERE curr_timestamp BETWEEN '$small_formatted' AND '$large_formatted'
ORDER BY curr_timestamp ASC
```

Where `$small_formatted` and `$large_formatted` are properly formatted times using something like `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $input_timestamp)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Switch the order of your logic. You do not want your process to be an `else`.
2. It seems like you are combining procedural and object styles. Pick one.
3. You should avoid selecting all (`SELECT *`). Always specify a column list.
4. The dates are not formatted correctly. You should format your input date to match the database format (`YYYY-MM-DD`). I am assuming that `curr_timestamp` is `YYYY-MM-DD`.
5. You need to stop using `mysql_` functions as they are being [deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql).
6. Use prepared statements to prevent SQL injections.

I have not tested this, but this fixes the issues I've listed above:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['find']))
{
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user_name", "password", "stock");

    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 'SELECT * FROM main_stock WHERE curr_timestamp ' . 
    "BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(?, '%m-%d-%Y') " . 
    "AND DATE_FORMAT(?, '%m-%d-%Y') ORDER BY curr_timestamp");

    mysqli_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $_POST['small'], $_POST['large']) or die(mysqli_error($dbh));

    $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_error($link));

    echo "<table width = '500' align = 'center'>";
    echo "<tr><b>";
    echo "<td>Product Description</td>";
    echo "<td>New or Own?</td>";
    echo "<td>Date</td>";
    echo "</b></tr>";

    while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $record[product_desc] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $record[newown] . "</td>";

        $year_part_of_date = explode('-', $record[curr_timestamp]);

    echo "<td>".$year_part_of_date[0]."</td>";

        //if you want the full date replace the $year_part_of_date[0] with $record->date
    echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";

   mysqli_close($link);
}
else
{
?>
<form method = "post" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<table width = "450" align = "center">
    <tr>
    <td><b><i>Please enter date in the field below (i.e. 11-09-2012)</i></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    From&nbsp;:&nbsp;
    <input type = "text" name = "small">
    To&nbsp;:&nbsp;
    <input type = "text" name = "large"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align = "center">
        <input type = "submit" name = "find" value = "SEARCH">
        <input type = "reset" value = "CLEAR FORM">
        </td>   
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}

?>
```